# How to hide kendo jquery chart value axis unit labels

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

[image: Kendo Chart]

I am trying to draw a line chart where a value axis and category axis will intersect at some point using kendo jquery chart.

I followed up this question on kendo forum https://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamic-vertical-line-in-charts

I choose to create multiple value axes. So far i am able to draw the graph as shown below but not able to remove the unit labels from the value axis on the left.

Can anyone help on how to remove the **unit labels** from the blue value axis or any better approach is available?

Here is sample code:

```
function drawChart(data) {
   var series = [
      {
         name: "Series1",
         color: "#96DF73",
         markers: {
            visible: false
         },
         data: data.Series1
      },
      {
         color: "#00B0F2",
         width: 4,
         markers: {
            visible: false
         },
         data: Array.from({ length: 8 }).fill(3.2)
      }
   ];

   $("#divChart").kendoChart({
      legend: {
         position: "top"
      },
      seriesDefaults: {
         type: "line",
         style: "smooth",
         tooltip: {
            visible: true
         },
         axis: "defaultCatAxis"
      },
      chartArea: {
         background: "#f1f1f1"
      },
      plotArea: {
         background: "white"
      },
      series: multiSpeedSeries,
      categoryAxis: {
         title: {
            text: "Category"
         },
         categories: [0, 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000],
         axisCrossingValues: [0, 5],
         justified: true,
         minorGridLines: {
            visible: true
         }
      },
      valueAxes: [
         {
            name: "defaultCatAxis",
            title: {
               text: "defaultCatAxis"
            },
            minorGridLines: {
               visible: true
            },
            min: 1
         },
         {
            labels: {
               //width: 3,
               visibility: false
            },

            line: {
               color: "#00B0F2",
               width: 4
            }
         }
      ]
   });
}
```

Comment: if I have read the question correctly I think this dojo may help: https://dojo.telerik.com/otuBehiq if it is I will add it as an answer for you.

Comment: @DavidShorthose I wanted to remove the unit label/text from the blue value/vertical axis

Comment: like this; https://dojo.telerik.com/otuBehiq/2

Comment: yes,this will work. Hide the minor units as well, missed to add it in question

Comment: i have tweaked the last dojo so it hides the minor lines for you https://dojo.telerik.com/otuBehiq/2

Comment: I meant the minor units not lines, you can post the answer. I will add the hiding of minor units later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was pretty much there with the way you were doing the labelling it was simply some `typos` with property definitions:

See dojo for the example: dojo.telerik.com/otuBehiq/2

All I did was correct your axis definition from:

```
 {
            labels: {
               //width: 3,
               visibility: false
            },

            line: {
               color: "#00B0F2",
               width: 4
            }
         }
```

to :

```
 {
                    labels: {
                        //width: 3,
                        visible:false
                    },

                    line: {
                        color: '#00B0F2',
                        width: 4,
                    }
                }
```

notice it is `visible` rather than `visibility`

as for the second part of your question in the comments you will need to expand on what you actually need/expect from the chart as it isn't clear as I have removed the minor values and grid lines from the chart.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue. I was not able to spot this difference